# What is the difference between NetWeaver and NetWeaver administrator?

Tags: sap-basis, netweaver

Can somebody tell me the differences between NetWeaver and NWA? I guess NetWeaver platform is for both Java and ABAP stacks. But NetWeaver Administrator is only for Java.

Can someone point some basic differences between the two?

Answer (score 1):

The Netweaver Administrator is a set of tooling for Netweaver in which you can, for example, manage users on the Java stack. SAP Netweaver is the software layer on which it runs.

See more info for SAP Netweaver here:

- http://scn.sap.com/community/netweaver-administrator/blog/2012/11/19/what-is-sap-netweaver

See more info for SAP Netweaver Administrator here:

- https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwce10/helpdata/en/45/2bdafff14003c3e10000000a1553f6/content.htm